# Open list element in modal view from a site page

Tags: list, javascript, modal-dialog, hyperlink

I'm trying to include a link in a site page that leads to a specific element of a list..

I need the link to open the element détails in a modal dialog box instead of sending me directly into the element details within the list..

Is there a way that any links to elements in a specific links automatically open in a modal dialog box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using jQuery like:

```
<button onclick="javascript:popup(); return false;">Modal</button>

function popup(){
 SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ 
            url: "URL of List", 
            title: "Title of page", 
            allowMaximize: true, 
            showClose: true, 
            width: 850, 
            height: 600, 
            dialogReturnValueCallback: newCallback 
        });
function newCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { 
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out to make it work by adding some code directly to the hyperlink.

```
javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog("/SharePointSite/Lists/ListId/DispForm.aspx?ID=1");
```

links are now opening correctly.